# How to view template compiler error details in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015

I am working with Visual Studio 2015 and I'm getting a lot of compiler errors but I can't figure out where the root cause of those is:

[image: Compiler errors in Visual Studio]

Double-clicking on the highlighted error takes me into the `list` file to the `operator==`:

```
template<class _Ty,
class _Alloc> inline
bool operator==(const list<_Ty, _Alloc>& _Left,
    const list<_Ty, _Alloc>& _Right)
{   // test for list equality
return (_Left.size() == _Right.size()
    && _STD equal(_Left.begin(), _Left.end(), _Right.begin()));
}
```

Well, that doesn't help. Since I am working on a huge project, I don't know where the root cause of that error is, i.e. where is the code which uses the `std::list` in a way that causes this error?

I think XCode shows a stack for such errors, if I remember correctly.
How can I find out where this error originates?

Comment: IIRC there's also a build console window where you can inspect the raw text output including associated notes.

Comment: Nothing above or below this? Visual Studio is really a piece of that? My VIm give me better error management...

Comment: The 'Output' tab, specifically. Ctrl-Alt-O should bring it up, if the shortcut is the same as on MSVS2013

Comment: Double click on that line, switch to the build output, scroll down, until you find you code  and double click there (annoying !)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but also in the 'Output' tab there isn't much extra info. For the specific case above there is no additional detail-line, for other errors there are, but they are not refering to the code which is using the list (which I am searching), but only to some other point inside the `vc\include\list` file - so, that doesn't help either, unfortunately.

Comment: For anyone who is struggling with similar issues: I'm quite sure that it is some kind of internal Visual Studio bug, caused by Visual Studio not being able to handle some kind of `#include` order which was no problem with GCC or Clang compilers. My "solution" was to comment out and rearrange (arbitrarily?) the `#include` directives in my source files until I got more meaningful compiler errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the Output tab (Ctrl+Alt+O) shows all the messages from the compiler. The Error List tab just shows one message, the actual error, which, as you said, for template compilation problems is not very helpful. What I have found works rather well (it is a little tedious, but it does work), is to

1. Double click on the message in the Error List tab.
2. Switch to the Output tab
3. Step to next message in the chain using F8 (shift-F8 steps to previous message)

Comment: Yes, the Output-tab might provide some additional info IF that internal Visual Studio bug does not occur which I have described in a comment.

Comment: Sometimes sending the preprocessor output to a file (``/P`` compiler flag) has helped me track down similar problems.